# Where's this waterfront in Yokohama, featured in Episode 31 of "Terrace House: Boys & Girls in the City"?

Tags: japan, identify-this

These screenshots are from Episode 31 of  "Terrace House: Boys & Girls in the City", which I first saw [on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/terracehouse/comments/4lu0zl/misakis_apartment_is_so_disgusting/d3qpld4/). I can't spot the scene beneath in  [this map created by a fan](https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?mid=13T6nXZcJkK49AZAjj-34wfrNr_c&ll=35.11472882438712%2C144.7772890996555&z=5).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this show on Netflix, watched that part, there's a scene from a different angle that showed landmarks that I could find easily in Google Maps, then managed to get the same exact spot:

From the show:

[image]

Google Maps Street View:

[image]

Finally, this is [Google Maps link](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Cup+Noodle+Museum+Park/@35.4566754,139.6384869,3a,75y,247.47h,93.05t/data=!3m11!1e1!3m9!1sAF1QipOmeSV5OM4YuBf-wm1stzwSdjLtJ04Ec1uLMVXO!2e10!3e11!6shttps:%2F%2Flh5.googleusercontent.com%2Fp%2FAF1QipOmeSV5OM4YuBf-wm1stzwSdjLtJ04Ec1uLMVXO%3Dw203-h100-k-no-pi0-ya333.26-ro-0-fo100!7i10000!8i5000!9m2!1b1!2i38!4m8!1m2!2m1!1samusement+park!3m4!1s0x60185c5a3bd93f75:0x91874608b5b84cc1!8m2!3d35.4561!4d139.6391454)